# ANTLR API issue ; example + workaround provided ; explanation required

Tags: java, antlr

I created the following Lexer using ANTLRWorks. ( See also http://bkiers.blogspot.com/2011/03/2-introduction-to-antlr.html#intro )

```
 // CSVLexer.g
 lexer grammar CSVLexer;

 @lexer::header {
   package graphica.parsers;
 }

 Comma   
   :  ','  
   ;  

 LineBreak  
  :  '\r'? '\n'  
  |  '\r'  
  ;  

 SimpleValue  
   :  ~(',' | '\r' | '\n' | '"')+  
   ;  

 QuotedValue  
   :  '"' ('""' | ~'"')* '"'  
   ;
```

I used the following Java class to test the Lexer.

```
 /**
  *
  * @author Nilo
  */
 import org.antlr.runtime.*;

 public class CSVLexerTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // the input source  
    String source =
            "val1, value2, value3, value3.2" + "\n"
            + "\"line\nbreak\",ABAbb,end";

    // create an instance of the lexer  
    CSVLexer lexer = new CSVLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(source));
    // wrap a token-stream around the lexer  
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);


    // traverse the tokens and print them to see if the correct tokens are created
    // tokens.toString();
    int n = 1;
    for (Object o : tokens.getTokens()) {
        CommonToken token = (CommonToken) o;
        System.out.println("token(" + n + ") = " + token.getText().replace("\n",    "\\n"));
        n++;
    }
 }
 }
```

The class above ( from the same tutorial ) does NOT produce any output. If I however insert a tokens.toString() prior to the token loop then output is printed as expected.

Note: I use ANTLWorks 1.4.3, ANTLR 3.4, on Windows 7 with JDK 1.7/64bit

**QUESTION: I don't understand this. Please explain. There should be a way to get this working without the tokens.toString()**

Comment: There has been a change since ANTLR 3.2 (it works with ANTLR 3.2). See the comments in next part of the tutorial: http://bkiers.blogspot.com/2011/03/3-lexical-analysis-of-tl.html If/when I find what has changed, I'll post it here (don't hold your breath though! :)).

Comment: @BartKiers - It works with the workaround; but that doesn't feel good. Thanks for the tutorial, it is the best. ( And I have both books of Terence Parr )

Comment: I fully agree that it doesn't feel right. That's why I want to delve into the source to see _why_ this happens since 3.3 and upwards. But there's always something more important when I have a couple of free hours... :). As I said, whenever I find out, I'll report back here. And thank you for your kind words!

Comment: Of course, I couldn't let it rest! :) See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CommonTokenStream` extends `BufferedTokenStream` which has a `List<Token> tokens` that is returned when one calls `getTokens()`. But this `List<Token> tokens` only gets filled at certain times. In 3.3 and 3.4 it does *not* happen after `getTokens()` where 3.2 *does* fill the `tokens` list.

### ANTLR 3.2 (and before)

```java
public List getTokens() {
    if ( p == -1 ) {
        fillBuffer();
    }
    return tokens;
}

protected void fillBuffer() {
    // fill `tokens`
}
```

### ANTLR 3.3 (and after)

```java
public List getTokens() { 
    return tokens; 
}

public void fill() {
    // fill `tokens`
}
```

Notice how 3.2's fill method is protected and in 3.3+ it is public, so the following works:

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class CSVLexerTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // the input source  
    String source =
        "val1, value2, value3, value3.2" + "\n" + 
        "\"line\nbreak\",ABAbb,end";

    // create an instance of the lexer  
    CSVLexer lexer = new CSVLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(source));

    // wrap a token-stream around the lexer and fill the tokens-list 
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    tokens.fill();

    // traverse the tokens and print them to see if the correct tokens are created
    // tokens.toString();
    int n = 1;
    for (Object o : tokens.getTokens()) {
      CommonToken token = (CommonToken) o;
      System.out.println("token(" + n + ") = " + token.getText().replace("\n",    "\\n"));
      n++;
    }
  }
}
```

producing the output:

```
token(1) = val1
token(2) = ,
token(3) =  value2
token(4) = ,
token(5) =  value3
token(6) = ,
token(7) =  value3.2
token(8) = \n
token(9) = "line\nbreak"
token(10) = ,
token(11) = ABAbb
token(12) = ,
token(13) = end
token(14) = <EOF>
```