# ANTLR - non-deterministic behaviour during run/debug

Tags: java, antlr, non-deterministic

I'm trying to use ANTLR (tried 3.3 and 3.4). Strange thing happens when I try to run my test code. Please see my very simple code first, I'll explain my problem afterwards.

Test grammar:

```
lexer grammar CSVLexer;
Comma 
  :  ','
  ;
LineBreak
  :  '\r'? '\n'
  |  '\r'
  ;
SimpleValue
  :  ~(',' | '\r' | '\n' | '"')+
  ;
QuotedValue
  :  '"' ('""' | ~'"')* '"'
  ;
```

Test code:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
public class JMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String source = "val1,val2,val3";
        CSVLexer lexer = new CSVLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(source));
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        int n = 1;
        for (Object o : tokens.getTokens()) {
            CommonToken token = (CommonToken) o;
            System.out.println("token(" + n + ") = " + token.getText().replace("\n", "\\n"));
            n++;
        }
    }
}
```

Compiation:

```
$ export CLASSPATH=antlr3.jar
$ java org.antlr.Tool CSVLexer.g
$ javac *.java
$ java JMain
```

The first problem is that it doesn't print anything :). I work in Intellij IDEA (10) and I tried to run the code from here without success (with ANTLR in CLASSPATH). HOWEVER, if I put breakpoint on `int i = 1`, debug and wait, say 1-3 seconds before continuing, it works! If I run it in debug mode without breakpoint it doesn't. Could someone please explain to me what could be the problem? Thank you.

EDIT:

So I tried tu put:

```
tokens.fill()
```

right after

```
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
```

and it worked. However then I started debugging *CommonTokenStream* constructor (several mins) and when I got on `tokens.fill()` I got IndexOutOfBoundException. So somehow something in background did something but I can't see no other threads in IDEA.

EDIT2:

Problem solved. It appears that it is necessary to call `fill()` first and that `BufferedTokenStream` probably wasn't  meant to be used like this. I followed this tutorial http://bkiers.blogspot.com/2011/03/2-introduction-to-antlr.html where it probably somehow worked for author (I wonder why). IntelliJ IDEA debugger called `toString()` on local objects and it in turn called `fill()` so that's why it worked when I set breakpoint. `toString()` modyfing state is evil!

Comment: There was a change in the API from 3.2 to 3.3+. See this previous Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560556/antlr-api-issue-example-workaround-provided-explanation-required Note that I made a comment about this `.fill()` method in the code snippet in my tutorial.

Comment: @Bart Kiers: Hello. Looks like I was blind x(. Thanks for your tutorials, they are very helpful.

Comment: No, you were not blind. I added the comment in the tutorial about the `.fil()` method *after* you posted your question here! :)